# Microsoft Access script cannot connect to device camera

Tags: windows, ms-access, camera, driver, webcam

I have been working on an Access Database where the user can click a button and the code will access the "webcam" present on the computer and then proceed to take a picture. The code works fine on regular laptops but I tried running it on a Laptop/Tablet hybrid (Latitude 5290 2-in-1 Laptop) and for whatever reason, the code does not access the camera at all.

I downloaded a third party app called Dorgem and tried to access the camera but got an error saying "Failed to connect to device." To me, it sounds like a permission issue but I made sure that camera permission is enabled in settings (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/71414-allow-deny-os-apps-access-camera-windows-10-a.html). I strongly believe that it is still a permission issue but I cannot find a way around it. I would really appreciate if I can get some input on how to solve this issue.

Here is the code I have been using in access.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public ImageLocation As String
Public AttachmentIndicator As String
Const WS_CHILD As Long = &H40000000
Const WS_VISIBLE As Long = &H10000000


Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
Const WM_CAP_START As Long = WM_USER


Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 10
Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 11
Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW As Long = WM_CAP_START + 50
Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE As Long = WM_CAP_START + 52
Const WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 41
Const WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB As Long = WM_CAP_START + 25


Private Declare PtrSafe Function capCreateCaptureWindow _
    Lib "avicap32.dll" Alias "capCreateCaptureWindowA" _
         (ByVal lpszWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Long _
        , ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long _
        , ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr _
        , ByVal nID As Long) As Long



Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long _
        , ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long


Dim hCap As LongPtr

Private Sub TakePictureButton_Click()
Dim sFileName As String
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(False), 0&)
    sFileName = "C:\Users\212764307\Documents\" & Forms!IRForm.IRNO & ".jpg"
    ImageLocation = sFileName


    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, 0&, ByVal CStr(sFileName))

DoFinally:
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(True), 0&)

End Sub

Private Sub Cmd3_Click()
Dim Temp As Long
Temp = SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0&, 0&)
DoCmd.Close
End Sub


Private Sub StartCameraButton_Click()
    hCap = capCreateCaptureWindow("Take a Camera Shot", WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, PicWebCam.Width, PicWebCam.Height, PicWebCam.Form.hWnd, 0)
    If hCap <> 0 Then
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0)
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0&)
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(True), 0&)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd2_Click()
Dim Temp As Long
Temp = SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT, 0&, 0&)
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
StartCameraButton.Caption = "Start Camera"
cmd2.Caption = "&Format Cam"`enter code here`
cmd3.Caption = "&Close Cam"
TakePictureButton.Caption = "&Take Picture"

End Sub'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use newest version of avicap32.dll (copy to windows\system32 and windows\sysWOW64 directories,also check camera drivers, there is always problem on them with avicap.